# Windows azure caching top10 picture blobs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Hello fellow programmers,

First i would like to say im new with caching and have never used it before..

This is a azure website with table & blob storage. I'm using Azure Cache Service.
I want my top10 blob pictures to be cached. My top10 view uses @model IEnumerable

This is my top10 action before fooling around with caching: (working)

```
public ActionResult TopPictures()
{
    picturesList.Clear();
    CloudTable table = _Service.GetCloudTable();
    CloudBlobContainer blob = _Service.GetCloudBlobContainer();

    TableQuery<PictureEntity> query = new TableQuery<PictureEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "bilder"));

    var tablelist = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
    var entity = (from e in tablelist
                  orderby e.AverageRating descending
                  select e).Take(10);

    return View(entity);
}
```

This is my top10 action after fooling around with caching:

```
    DataCache cache = new DataCache("default");

    public ActionResult TopPictures()
    {
        picturesList.Clear();
        CloudTable table = _Service.GetCloudTable();
        CloudBlobContainer blob = _Service.GetCloudBlobContainer();

        var cache = new DataCache("default");
        object cacheTop = cache.Get("top");

        if (cacheTop == null)
        {
            TableQuery<PictureEntity> query = new TableQuery<PictureEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "bilder"));

            var tablelist = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
            var entity = (from e in tablelist
                          orderby e.AverageRating descending
                          select e).Take(10);
            cache.Add("top", entity);

            return View(entity);
        }

        return View(cacheTop);
    }
```

Am i returning the right items here? (cachetop if not null and entity if null)

When i navigate to top10 I get an InvalidDataContractException at cache.Add("top", entity);
The error mention something about PictureEntity cannot be serialized..

I would love some help from you guys, thanks

Comment: I've added [Serializable] to my pictureentity class but it did not help.

Comment: Please provide PictureEntity class implementation. A suggestion, Did you consider using ASP.NET Output caching? why do you need to store explicitly Entity object in cache? do not make Caching as your business logic, just use output caching, and configure custom caching provider to Azure caching, so ASP.net and Azure will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its a matter of taste. Ill try output caching next time, but it wont solve this problem.

I solved it by adding: **select e).Take(10).ToList();**

Thanks your for help:)